Short story about a neurodivergent child who becomes a pilot
Many years ago, there was a short story (I think in a May issue of Asimov's magazine or whatever it became later) about a neurodivergent child (perhaps Williams disease).
In this society, this was excluded and the mother hid the child (the father had deserted them upon diagnosis). One day, authorities come to her house and begin assessing the child. She is worried that the local authorities will take the child and hide it away, but it turns out that these guys are recruiters for starships, because this neurodivergence gives the child an advantage in astronavigation.
The mother is still sad, because she will be separated from her child, but cut to the end, the starship found her a role, too. Think maybe it was called "Mother's Day."

N.B.: It's not any of the stories from the anthology, Isaac Asimov's Mother's Day

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "many years ago?"  Are we talking 5 years ago or 20?

+1 Note on edit: Diversity (including neurodiversity) is a characteristic of a group, not an individual. Individuals are divergent (including neurodivergent), or not.

I think this is Mother to Elves by Michael Armstrong. The description matches, though it was published in The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, June 1994 not in Asimov's. According to ISFDB this is the only place it has been published.
The girl is Clara and she does have Williams' syndrome. The title refers to the elvish appearance that goes with the condition. Her mother is Beatrice.
The story starts at a doctor's surgery where Clara is diagnosed with the syndrome. Then Beatrice is visited by a team from the Navy:

So the naval officers explained it gently to her, one step at a time, so when Mrs. Thompson fully understood what they meant to do, she had to believe it. That Clara had Williams' Syndrome, that she was an elf . . . to the Navy, that meant one thing: she was special, and they wanted to take Clara away, away into space.
SPACE," SAID the tall woman, who told Mrs. Thompson her name was Anne, "space isn't quite what it seems. We think we understand it, but what we understand is like the soap that makes the bubble and we can't see through it to the air. You know what makes the bubble and you can see its shape, but suppose you didn't understand pressure, or air, or surface tension. You wouldn't understand the bubble, not really."
Mrs. Thompson nodded, politely, because she didn't see the point.
Anne sipped her tea and put it down. "It takes a special mind to understand space, to understand the inside of the bubble, the place we take our starships to get to other worlds. I understand that space a little bit, intellectually, I think, but I can't feel it. I could take you into that space but I couldn't get you out. To get out, we need someone who understands it, who feels it. So far, the only ones who can . . . are people like Clara."
People like Clara? It began to dawn on her, a bit. "She's special, I know that."
"You don't know how special. Do you know how many other elfin children there are on this planet, in all the known worlds, out. of all those innumerable billions of souls? None on Beyond, and of all humankind -barely fifty! Like so many genetic defects, we cured the pool of such problems. Only because not everyone has been completely screened has it been that the gene for Williams' Syndrome still exists. We'd change it back but first we have to find enough elfin children."

Normally the children are taken from their parents to be trained as pilots immediately after birth, but Clara was diagnosed late and the mother daughter bond has already formed. The Navy agreed to take Beatrice as crew so mother and daughter could stay together. The story ends:

Beatrice saw it then, saw her future and Clara's future. She would spend the rest of her life in space, on the school ship where they trained the navigators, the very ship the Mother Theresa now sped toward to deliver its two new crew.
Traveling in the same general subjective time as Clara would when she got her assignment, mother and daughter would grow old together, see each other often, and never be apart. Mother to Clara; mother to elves.


Arrgghhhhh, this was on the tip of my tongue. I can't believe I forgot the name of the main character...

I knew I'd have to work fast to beat you :-)

Wondering how being cut off from their parents or not would affect the children.

Ironically, in real life, people with William's syndrome tend to have rather worse spatial reasoning capabilities than the general population, but high verbal communication skills. I guess the author did not do their research very well....

Could this be a partial match to Gloriously Bright by Orson Scott Card?
This story was published in Analog Science Fiction and Fact in January 1991, and also as expanded in his Xenocide novel.
It has been a number of years since I read it, so bear with me on the details.
The protagonist(s) have been genetically manipulated to be super-intelligent (called "Godspoken"). Fearing that this would allow them to overtake the government, the intelligence is linked with an obsessive compulsive disorder (OCD) as a control mechanism.
This is a multi-generational story, where the parents of the main subject, are so called "godspoken" and involved in solving high-level governmental/political problems. Great things are expected from their daughter (the main subject) when she exhibits tendencies of OCD. Her father starts to pass some of his tasks on to her.
She solves a problem of a missing fleet of starships, which it turns out was hidden deliberately by a supercomputer/AI that "lives" in the supra-luminal communicators and computers connected to them. Previously no-one, apart from Ender Wiggin, had suspected that such an entity was possible and the main subject threatens to reveal the AI to the interstellar government and get it taken down. IIRC the AI fights back and threatens to cut off communications between planets (?), but is manipulated somehow into not doing this.
I don't recall any parts where the main subject is going to be taken away (it has been a loooong time), but she is subjected to tests by the authorities, and interstellar travel does take relativistic time-frames, so having to travel to another world might take 30 years or more. I also don't recall her becoming a pilot - I think this is all done by computers (not AI) too.
